# Employee Training & Procedure Log

Tags: web-apps, hosted

I'm looking for something that will:

- Log training topics
- Log staff progress against a given topic
- Allow for review dates
- Ideally allow for attaching documents like visio procedures.
- Use a database (not spreadsheet based like SmartSheet).

Preferably hosted - but happy with on-prem. Gratis not required.

Comment: Assuming web-app? Free or Paid?

Comment: Web app. Don't mind a license fee.